# PHP json_encode() returning Undefined to $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm creating an array in php and then using json_encode() before getting it with $.getJSON but it returns Undefined. If I send just one row to JS it working fine (json_encode($classes[0])) but when I try to send all the data it returns Undefined. Any ideas?

Here is a little of the array which is generated by querying the database and returning the results...

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Record_Type] => S
            [Convention_ID] => 
            [Event_ID] => 19030145
            [Sponsor_ID] => Google
            [Course_ID] => 2837199
            [Last_Modified_Date_Time] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2019-02-25 10:03:36.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => US/Pacific
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Record_Type] => S
            [Convention_ID] => 
            [Event_ID] => 19030111
            [Sponsor_ID] => Google
            [Course_ID] => 2837192
            [Last_Modified_Date_Time] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2019-02-21 07:23:47.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => US/Pacific
                )

        )
```

here is the php minus the SQL statement...

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$classes = array();
while( $class = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $classes[] = $class;
}

echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($classes).')';
```

and here is the Javascript which I'm using to get the JSON data...

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://example/api/education.php?callback=?",
        function(data) {        
            console.log(data);          
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Is yor php script returning a valid JSON?

Comment: @asiby how can I check?

Comment: Navigate directly to "https://example/api/education.php?callback=?" the same way jQuery is doing it. But in your case, just enter the URL in a browser and watch what will be displayed. You would want to replace the second `?` with the proper value.

Comment: Check it by using var_dump();

Comment: @asiby When I navigate directly to the URL it returns ?() and I'm not sure what you mean by "replace the second ? with the proper value". What value should I have there?

Comment: Ok. The PHP script you have is getting some data from a database and after some processing, it is outputting the result using the `echo` statement. It's the result of that statement that I am referring to as "the return". And it that printed information that will come back as `data` in you jQuery call. Now, if you look at your jQuery, part of it looks like `$.getJSON("https://example/api/education.php?callback=?" ...`. This is not a valid URL. You cannot have two question marks in a URL. Replace the second one with the value that you want to assign to the callback querystring.

Comment: And from what I am seeing, the output of the PHP script can never be a valid JSON because it looks like a function which name is specified by `$_GET['callback']` and the parameter will be a JSON string that may or may not be able to pass through an eval() in Javascript if that's what you are planning.

Comment: @asiby I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5pXxS0y4bg but from what you are saying I'm guessing the tutorial is incorrect. I understand some of what you're saying but I don't understand how to fix it. Can you give me more details regarding exactly what should be changed? Everything works fine if I'm only returning one row like echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($classes[0]).')'; but when I try and return all data echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($classes).')'; it's Undefined

Comment: @asiby "the value that you want to assign to the callback querystring" I don't really understand what the ? should be changed to.

Comment: Ok. I will stop using any other terminologies because they are causing more questions. Here is my simple answer ... the URL you are passing to $.getJSON() is not valid because a URL cannot have 2 question marks in it.

Comment: @asiby I really don't think that's the problem since multiple tutorials say to do it that way. Here is another one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FntaH8yH4Eg and as I mentioned it works fine when returning one row instead of all data.

Comment: Sure. Then I am done here. And in that case, you might want to check with the author of that YouTube video. He is probably still taking questions.

Comment: I found the problem. It wasn't in the code it was in the data returned from the SQL query. This character � was part of  a string stored in the database. That one character somehow made the JSON return Undefined. When I removed � from the database everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It wasn't in the code it was in the data returned from the SQL query. This character � was part of a string stored in the database. That one character somehow made the JSON return Undefined. When I removed � from the database everything started working fine.